# I have ear file in my Rational Application Developer(RAD) still I cannot Add Project to WebSphere 6.1 local server

Tags: websphere, rad, websphere-6.1

I am using RAD 8.0 with WebSphere 6.1.

When I right click on the Server in the Servers View and select "Add and Remove..." I get a dialog saying "There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server."

What am I missing to get it to let me add my project to the server?

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere 6.1 supports only Java EE 1.4 applications, so if you by chance created new Java EE 5 or 6 EAR you will not be able to deploy it to 6.1.

Comment: The Project Facets view contains a message like this: This project is not configured to use project facets. Converting this project to faceted form will allow you to easily control the available technologies. Convert to faceted form... For the ear file.

Comment: This project is an imported project

Comment: @ranju You need to convert to facet project, and select EAR facet in EAR, and appropriate ones in web/ejb modules.